# How to I properly save the data inside of a listview item throughout the activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, listview, android-lifecycle, listitem

I have created a listview that displays a daily quote (one listVite item with 4 textviews containing text data) from a local SQLite database in the MainActivity. This updates at a specified time each day via alarm manager and broadcast receiver. I need to retain the text from the (4) textViews inside of a listview accross any type of lifecycle change. I need it to persist  if the user a. rotates the screen b. force closes the app and comes back to it before the specified time to re-populate with a different quote c. navigates to a different activity and comes back to the MainActivity... etc.

I have read the other posts and even though some of the titles seem to ask this question the actual post appears to be different. Any ideas? Much appreciated.

I have tried saved instance state using this code: (it didn't work)

```
 mState = mDailyVerseListView.onSaveInstanceState();
 mDailyVerseListView.onRestoreInstanceState(mState);
```

Here is the method where I pull the daily quote from the SQLite Database:

```
public void DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess(){

SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new SQLiteAssetHelper(this, 
DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
SQLiteDatabase SqlDb = sqLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM dailyQuoteTable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 
1";
Cursor cursor = SqlDb.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
DailyQuoteCursorAdapter DQCursorAdapter = new DailyQuoteCursorAdapter(this, 
cursor);
this.mDailyQuoteListView.setAdapter(DQCursorAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need it to persist if the user a. rotates the screen b. **force
>   closes the app** and comes back to it before the specified time to
>   re-populate with a different quote c. navigates to a different
>   activity and comes back to the MainActivity
>
> I have created a listview that displays a daily quote (one listVite
>   item **with 4 textviews containing text data**) from a local SQLite
>   database in the MainActivity.

Because you need to hold data after force close and also your data is four strings. It is better for you to use `SharedPreferences` to save and retrieve data.

when you read data from `SQLite` save it in `SharedPreferences` and in `onResume` of Activity read it from `SharedPreferences` also set Activity as listener for this `SharedPreference` in `onResume` (after reading it) and remove Activity from `SharedPreference` listener in `onPause`

Comment: Thank you Bahman. So would I need to save it in my custom adapter or in the main activity and would I need to save the individual textView's data or the adapter itself? That is kinda where I am confused. I am not able to use "getText()" to access the listView's list item that contains the textViews when I try to do it outside of the onItemClick method. Any ideas on the proper way to do what you suggested?

Comment: @Stark if the texts would not be changed in your activity then why you need to save them in your activity? you save them when reading from SQLite db. first say where and when the texts will be changed?

Comment: @Stark if texts do not change through adapter you can save texts when reading from db via alarm manager. and register for listening to changes in activity

Comment: Thanks again Bahman. Yeah I think that's where I am getting confused. The listView exists on the users screen in the MainActivity. The method in this question is in the main activity but I used a custom adapter class, listed in the above method as DailyQuoteCursorAdapter, to populate the listView in the way that I want it with the information from the DB. See, I have an onItemClickListener also in the mainActivity for the user to be able to click on the quote on and see a menu with options to perform different actions. I am able to get the textView values there because I can use view. Outside

Comment: continued... outside of onItemClickListener I can't seem to get access to those textViews inside of the listView item. The list item does change but only once a day controlled by alarm manager, I want the current data set in the list item to persist until it is the alarm time again which is the time for it to change to a new quote. I need it to persist between alarms no matter what the user does. I will look into what you said about saving them when reading from SQLite. I appreciate your help. I am open to any additional explanation. Thanks again Bahman.